# Solutions to $x^2+x-1\equiv 0$ mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

The problem is to find all prime number p such that the above congruence has solutions.
I started this problem by rearranging the equation such that:
$$
x(x+1)\equiv 1 \pmod{p}  
$$
The hint given was to use quadratic reciprocity however I don't see how to apply that to this problem. I did do some brute force work and found that there are no solutions for $p=2,7,13,17,23$ one solutions for $p=5$ and two solutions for $p=11,19,29$.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Comment: **Hint:**  The answer depends on whether $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.  Do strongly take @JavaMan's suggestion into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square is the most obvious approach. Starting from

$$x^2+x-1\equiv 0\pmod p$$

we want to make the LHS into a square, so we can discuss quadratic residues. Multiply through by $4$:
$$ 4x^2+4x-4\equiv 0\pmod p\iff (2x+1)^2\equiv 5\pmod p.$$
Hence for this congruence to have a solution, $5$ needs to be a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Can you continue from here? (Hint: try using Euler's Criterion.)

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is this correct: Basically, by the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity, the last equation you got can only be true iff p is a square (mod 5), i.e. $p\equiv +/-1 \pmod{5}$ or $p=5$.

Answer (score 2):

For odd $p$, multiply through by $4$ to get

$$4x^2+4x+1 \equiv 5 \pmod{p}.$$

Enough?